# How can upload image in custom extension in adminhtml controller file

Tags: image, magento

```
 public function saveAction()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            try {
                $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

                $bookingModel = Mage::getModel('booking/booking');

                $bookingModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->setTitle($postData['title'])
                    ->setContent($postData['content'])
                    ->setStatus($postData['status'])
                    ->setImage($postData['image'])
                    ->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item was successfully saved'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setbookingData(false);
           $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setbookingData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
```

// let me know how can be insert image in my extension if any suggestion please give me answer  this is working but just insert name of image ..

Answer (score 0):

You may add uploading directly using this code:

```
    protected function _uploadImageFile($name)
    {
        $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($name);
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);

        $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . self::IMAGE_FOLDER . DS;
        $uploader->save($path, $_FILES[$name]['name']);

        return $uploader->getUploadedFileName();
    }
```

usage:

```
    $postData['image'] = $this->_uploadImageFile('image');
```

Comment: Hello there i m trying but showing error $_FILES array is empty ..please check

Comment: add check for $_FILES array before use this function. if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))). And try add to your form $form->setEnctype('multipart/form-data');

Comment: $_FILES is global PHP array and when you upload image it must be not empty. Check method and enctype of your form. Method must be post, enctype - multipart/form-data. If $_FILES empty - something wrong with submitted data.